# How to use variables of a method in another method?

Tags: java

The question is simple, but can't figure out how:

how do I get back the vlues of namesInput and categoryInput?

```
public void create(){

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Name:");
        String nameInput = scan.next();
        System.out.println("Category:");
        String categoryInput = scan.next();
        System.out.println(nameInput + " " + categoryInput);
}

public void addToList(){

        names.add(nameInput);
        categories.add(categoryInput);

}
```

Comment: Read up on Java scope.

Comment: What stops you from passing these values as parameters to addToList? Or what stops you from storing these values as you scan them in some global data structure?

Comment: the compiler says: cannot find symbol, focusing on nameInput and categoryInput on the addToList method

Comment: Where do you call `addToList()` method?

Comment: can you post code where do you call this method in main method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) `cannot find symbol: nameInput, categoryInput on the addToList method`:

This is because you *defined* nameInput and categoryInput in create() ... but you're using them in "addToList().

The issue here is "[scope](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html)".

2) You have (at least) three choices:

- Pass the variables in as parameters
- Declare the variables globally (as static members)
- Eliminate "addToList()", and just execute these two lines as part of "create()".

3) I would recommend a combination of the latter two options:

```
public class MyClass {
  private List<String> names;
  private List<String> categories;
  ...

  public MyClass () {
     names = new ArrayList<String>();
     categories = new ArrayList<String>();
     ...

  public newItem () {     
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Name:");
      String nameInput = scan.next();
      System.out.println("Category:");
      String categoryInput = scan.next();
      names.add(nameInput);
      categories.add(categoryInput);
      System.out.println("newItem: " + nameInput + " " + categoryInput);
  }
```

4) Going further, it probably makes sense to define a *new* class; a class that has "name" and "category" as members.

Comment: To declare them global shouldn't I add public static before the type?

Comment: Sure that'd be the best thing to do, but the fact is I was willing to know how to get a variable from another method, by the wat I guess I just need to change pattern eh? I mean, that way wasn't proper compared to this new one

Answer (score 0):

Try to use parameters like this to avoid compiler error:

```
public void create(){

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Name:");
        String nameInput = scan.next();
        System.out.println("Category:");
        String categoryInput = scan.next();
        System.out.println(nameInput + " " + categoryInput);
}

public void addToList(int nameInput,int categoryInput){

        names.add(nameInput);
        categories.add(categoryInput);

}
```

And make sure you pass this parameters to this method

Answer (score 0):

You can move them to a higher scope (ie move them outside the method). The variable is only accessible until the end of the block that it is in (ie the matching '}' )

```
class Foo    
{  
    String nameInput;  
    String categoryInput;

    public void create(){

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Name:");
        nameInput = scan.next();
        System.out.println("Category:");
        categoryInput = scan.next();
        System.out.println(nameInput + " " + categoryInput);

     } //Variables like 'scan' can't be used past this brace

     public void addToList(int nameInput,int categoryInput){

        names.add(nameInput);
        categories.add(categoryInput);

    }

} //The two variables can't be used past here
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class clarify {

ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void main (String[] args){

    clarify clear = new clarify();

    clear.create();
    clear.addToList();
    clear.displayLists();
}

public void create(){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Name:");
    String nameInput = scan.next();
    System.out.println("Category:");
    String categoryInput = scan.next();
    System.out.println(nameInput + " " + categoryInput);
}

public void addToList(){

    names.add(nameInput);
    categories.add(categoryInput);

}

public void displayLists(){

        System.out.println(names.listIterator());

}

}
```

Comment: This not only fails to solve the question in your post - it doesn't even compile!

Comment: Yeap knew that, somebody asked for the entire code, by the way it's alright now thanks guys!